# pandas with xlsxwriter encoding caused 'u' prefix to dataframe text

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter to populate dataframe data to excel via the pandas to_excel function. However, the data populated has the prefix '**u**' infront of the text displayed in excel.

Output in Excel:
[**u**'05-Sep-17']
[**u**'05-Sep-17']

I understand that 'u' is referring to unicode, are there any means to remove the '**u**' prefix?

I have tried the following but without any success so far.

1) Handle it via regex before calling the func to_excel()

```
df.loc[:, 'delivery_dt'].replace({r'[^\x00-\x7F]+':''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The print statement gave the result I wanted but when it reaches the to_excel() stage, unicode 'u' prefix appeared in the final output in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but with no success. Do you mind sharing any more detail about the source of data you are importing?

If your strings are in unicode originally and you use `.to_excel('test.xls')` function, it should work with no problem. If you want to force a special encoding in Excel, use an argument `.to_excel('test.xls', encoding='utf16')`.

So, make sure that you know in what encoding is your original data (e.g. your csv files or your database). When loading to Python, always try to decode data in unicode as soon as possible. Then it should work out of the box.

```
df['delivery_dt'] = df['delivery_dt'].apply(lambda x: unicode(x))
```

Again, as always, using Python 3 makes your life much easier when it comes to non-ascii characters.

Comment: Hi, the source data is from a mssql db. Using pd.read_sql_query, I extracted out the data and load it into a dataframe object for further data transformations. I tried enforcing an encoding via the to_excel() but it still output the 'u' prefix.

Comment: Make sure that you are passing a correct encoding to the db engine that you are creating, I suppose with sql_alchemy.

Comment: I suspect the issue lies with the excel writer engine (xlsxwriter). After I applied the regex conversion to the delivery_dt as mentioned above, I did a print statement and it shows the dates without the 'u' prefix. However, the to_excel() portion reverted the changes applied to the 'u' prefix. Are there any means to enforce encoding for the writer such that the 'u' can be removed?

Comment: I am using pyodbc engine. Passing in the standard set of params such as username, pwd, database and driver. let me check the docs and see if an encoding can be enforced on pyodbc.

Comment: As said always try to work with unicode in your python scripts. See the edit example above.

Comment: Hi @Marjan Moderc, thanks for the suggestions. Very helpful in triaging the problem. What worked is actually upgrading from Python 2 to Python 3. Running in Python 2 gives the 'u' prefix whereas in Python 3, the 'u' prefix is not appearing after calling the to_excel().